# Needing to select duplicates from two columns

Tags: excel

I have two columns of data which have alternative data. One column contains all duplicate emails and another which has details of opt in information.

I need to run a query which will select all email addresses which are duplicates but also have different opt in values.

The file has 170,000 rows so I am unable to use any conditional formatting without freezing Excel.

Does anyone know of a work around for this type of situation?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  This is not a codewriting service, but exists to help you with your programming problems.  For the best assistance, provide samples of your source data; your desired results; and the attempts you have made to solve your problem along with a description of the problems you have run in to.  Also see the Help pages for information as to [How to ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and also [how to provide an example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: One non-code suggestion that might work, depending on your specifics, would be the `Remove Duplicates` method.

Comment: `Advanced Filtering` may also help return the unique records between the two columns. Then you can do a count on email addresses to see which ones occur more than once.